# SSMS v18.00 in MSSQL 2016

Tags: ssms

I have got MSSQL 2016 (SP2-CU11) (KB4527378) with SSMS v18.00. In this version SSMS I not able to create local DB SSISDB. SSMS offered me DB in AZURE DB only. If I use SSMS 17.9, all is OK and I create local SSISDB. Am I able to disable this functionality in SSMS 18.00?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is easy. In wizard after Create Catalog you have to enable "Enable CLR Integration", fill password and press enter. You must not press button "Create SSIS IR"